# Unreal 4.25 - Draw text to canvas does not get refreshed

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I setup a **texture** to have **text rendered on it with Draw Text**

it works once, but never gets refreshed

so I try to force it with **Event tick**, but it does not work

in the example below, I add a random char to the text buffer, it also works only once

the next iterations **does not update the texture**

what am I missing ?

thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Try having it go `Event Tick`->[BeginDrawCanvastoRenderTarget](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/BeginDrawCanvastoRenderTarget/index.html) -> add random char & draw text -> [EndDrawCanvastoRenderTarget](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/EndDrawCanvastoRenderTarget/index.html)

Comment: yes !! thanks you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreal needs a way to know when you are done drawing on the canvas so it can perform the update. That is what  [`BeginDrawCanvastoRenderTarget`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/BeginDrawCanvastoRenderTarget/index.html) and [`EndDrawCanvastoRenderTarget`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/EndDrawCanvastoRenderTarget/index.html) are for.

All you need to do is wrap the draw command(s) you would like to use in those nodes, and that will work perfectly fine.

[image: example]
screenshot credit: Phil123456